# What data type does ebean map to BYTEA?

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a Play! 2.0.2 application that needs to store some files in the database. we are using Ebean for our ORM. I believe I need a BYTEA column in my database to store the file, but I'm not sure what data type to use in my model.

Should I be using some kind of `Blob`? Or just a `byte[]`? Or is there another data type I should be using? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create blob with Ebean you need to use byte array with @Lob annotation

```
@Lob
public byte[] image;
```

You'll need to convert between File <-> byte array, so maybe it's easier to store files in filesystem? (besides storing files in FS is just cheaper than in DB)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We thought of storing them in the filesystem but file storage needs to be duplicated across production instances and we thought it would be a lot easier to just have the database manage that for us. I am currently using a byte array in my model and so far haven't needed the `@Lob` annotation. What purpose does it serve?

Comment: `@Lob` instructs Ebean to use 'blob' type for MySQL column while auto-generation of DDL